# Guard w/ RSpec2, Ruby1.9.3, Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, guard

I am running Guard successfully with notifications provided by Libnotify.

```
funkdified@funkdified-laptop:~/railsprojects/sample_app$ guard
Guard uses Libnotify to send notifications.
Guard is now watching at '/home/funkdified/railsprojects/sample_app'
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
...

Finished in 0.06053 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures
```

If I modify the spec file I am alerted as to the results of the test, both in the terminal and with a popup notification. If I modify a controller file, again tests run normally. However, when I modify routes.rb, the whole things falls on its face and Guard stops working normally and throws up an error. Anyone have any ideas?

Error:

```
Running: spec/routing
/home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/funkdified/railsprojects/sample_app/spec/routing (LoadError)
    from /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `map'
    from /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun
```

Forgot to mention, if I kill Guard and restart (after making changes to routes.rb) then Guard again performs normally, suggesting that a test has now failed:

```
funkdified@funkdified-laptop:~/railsprojects/sample_app$ guard
Guard uses Libnotify to send notifications.
Guard is now watching at '/home/funkdified/railsprojects/sample_app'
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
..F

Failures:

  1) PagesController GET 'about' returns http success
     Failure/Error: get 'about'
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.0576 seconds
3 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:21 # PagesController GET 'about' returns http success
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check your `spec` directory. It should have a `routing` sub-directory for routing specs. If not, just create an empty one. Apparently, RSpec does not create any sub-directories under `spec` when running `rails g rspec:install`, but guard expects it to be there.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have the following line in your `Guardfile`:

```
watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
```

If you don't have specs in `spec/routing`, then don't folder that you don't need. Change the line to:

```
watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec" }
```

Now, all your specs will run when you update your `routes.rb` file.